# Update stock_availables in Prestashop using python

Tags: python-3.x, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to update the stock quantity on Prestashop using PrestashopApi.

I have this and when I run it, it seems to remove the item from stock_availables.

```
api = PrestashopApi('https://internalorders.vaulteksafe.com/api', 'mykey')
data = {'stock_available': {'id': id, 'id_product': id_product, 'id_product_attribute': id_product_attribute, 'id_shop_group': '0', 'depends_on_stock': 0, 'out_of_stock': 0, 'quantity': 1000}}
res = api.edit('stock_availables', data)['stock_available']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the link of the api you are using?

Answer (score -1):

Looking [prestashopapi source-code](https://github.com/savaskoc/prestashop_api/blob/master/prestashop_api.py) the api.edit(stuff) funcion only do that:

```
def edit(self, path, data):
        return self._request('PUT', path, data=data) //PUT means UOPDATE,
```

maybe you're trying to update a stockavaiable.id that wasn't previously inserted with an api.add(stuff) call?